# Laravel 5 with cpanel redirect to default language URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, redirect

I have a Laravel 5.2 application on a cPanel hosting account in which I had to remove the "public" folder from the URL with the following `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now I need to redirect everything incoming to just the main domain/page `www.example.com` to be redirected to `www.example.com/en`.
I tried some examples but all of them break the local css and img.

Answer (score 0):

Reinventing the wheel is always a bad idea. What you should do is to setup your web server correctly by pointing it to a `public` directory and restarting it. Also, use original Laravel `.htaccess`.

After that use [Laravel localization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/localization).

Then you could just copy `Controller@method` you using for `/en` route and put it into `/` route.